# Check if time X has less than 15 minutes from time Y

Tags: php, strtotime

Here is what I am trying to solve.

```
$nextAppt = "3:45:23";
$keydata = "3:40:10";
```

I am trying to evaluate weather `$nextAppt != $keydata && is not less than 15 minutes to $keydata`.

`$keydata` by the way is an `array` of times that I am checking `$nextAppt` against.

```
foreach ($taken_time as $keydata ) {
    $moredata = strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($keydata))
    if($nextAppt != $keydata && $taken_time < $moredata ){  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

so

```
$diff = $time->diff($time2);
if ($diff->h == 0 && $diff->m < 15) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: @HillelPicciotto It is better to leave a comment for original author to fix the problem. Once you have 50 reputation you can leave comments for other users asking for clarification or improvement. If you would like to post an alternative answer you think would be better it would be perfect.

Comment: @HillelPicciotto @Dharman fixed an issue with my original answer. Thanks for the edit suggestion. I removed the `<?php` stuff as that's not important to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to convert the times while calculating the unix time stamps. Then it's a matter of just subtracting:

```
$nextAppt - 900 (15 minutes * 60 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Datetime object.

```
$keydata = new DateTime("3:40:10");
$nextAppt = new DateTime("3:45:23");
$diff = $keydata->getTimestamp() - $nextAppt->getTimestamp();
if (abs($diff) > 60*15)
{
  // TODO
}
```

Comment: I hate coming back from Holiday and trying to remember why something didnt work or what I was trying to get to work.  The $keydata is dynamic, I am using php date("G:i") to get that value. So is "new DateTime" necessary?

Comment: @Cam you can do new DateTime('now')

Comment: This was just causing so much chaos, so Instead I pulled the values, and are using javascript to find all this stuff.